# How to view / edit HTML/Scripts on Content Editor Web Part in SharepPoint Designer 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

For some reason I can't seem to find where I can edit the HTML/Scripts in a CEWP via SharePoint Designer. No issues via a browser.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could write it in a text file, then link to that file from within the CEWP properties